# Developing Android App with a LOT of large images

Tags: java, android, image, memory, resources

I am pretty new to Android development (have mercy on me), and am developing an application which will use a lot images (as they are now, the images are around 400KB-1.5MB each, and there will be at least 80 images). The images are all quite large, and I'm wondering what the "recommended" ways of dealing with large images are without hogging up space on the user's phone.

I would prefer if an internet connection wasn't required for using the app, but, as I am new to Android development, I'm not sure what the best options are.

Ideally, we would want the user to be able to switch between the images very quickly. What's the best way to minimize the amount of space the images will take up on the user's device while maintaining quick access to the image files?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't understood something but <2Mb is normal size for app resources. And you must not have some problems with it.

Comment: If you want to display image very quickly you can use Thumbnail image for each image. (Load thumbnail image first). Also you can use some image library like Picasso, ImageLoader... it's will helpful for load/caching.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on an app that does something very similar and here is what I am doing to display images to the user.

**Regarding loading images**

First I have a launcher activity that creates a series of objects which contain all of the information I need about the image. Here is a quick example:

```
public class ImageData() {
    private String mName, mDescription;
    private int mResID;

    ImageData(String name, String description, int resID) {
        mName = name;
        mDescription = description;
        mResID = resID;
    }
    // Any needed getters/setters or other functionality
}
```

I then pass an ArrayList of my ImageData to my main activity which displays a bunch of thumbnail images. Clicking on one of these images then opens a new activity which contains a series of related images. My application is fast and responsive so I think this approach would be acceptable for you. Whether or not is it the fastest is another thing. That depends on what you are doing with all of the images.

**Regarding where to store images**

I am storing my images in the drawables folder as this allows me to store the resource ID of the image using the image file's name.

```
resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "drawable",
    context.getPackageName());
```

Note that fileName should not include any extension such as .png or .jpg

**Regarding application size**
My application has 910 .png images. Some of these are thumbnails and the others are roughly 150KB in size. In the end the images take up 135 MB of space. The average application is probably in the realm of 25-50 MB but since your (and my) applications are dealing with lots of images I would think that the user would understand the increase in size.

By your estimations your images would take up about 120 MB of space. I wouldn't worry much about taking up too much space. If you were really worried then you could always store thumbnails of the images on the device and if the user wanted the full size image they could then grab it from a server.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, I understood your problem. You need to load some image in memory and show it for user. In background app need to load images that user can switch (for example, you load image 2, in background 1, 3). Then user switched on next image app need to recycle one image and load new (for example, user switched from 4 -> 5, it need to recycle image #3 and load image 6).
Also if image has size more then user can increase it then you need resize image after loading.

P.S. Sorry, for my English. If you cannot understand something I try explain you.

Comment: In background you can load as many image as you need (and system can) but it better if it be only 2 - 4 images. And also you can load in background images like device screen size and load original image only when user see it on display.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this way](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) to load effectively a large bitmap image to memory (Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory).